# React identify control or shift key pressed

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a table as follows

```
<div>
   <table>
     <tbody>
          {students.map(x)=> ( <tr onClick{(e)=>selectStudent(i)} ={><td>{x}</td></tr>)}
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Row click is working fine. My question how to capture control and shift keys along with mouse click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the click event has registered those keys being pressed.

[This article](https://codewithhugo.com/detect-ctrl-click-js-react-vue/) describes the process:

```js
    onClick={e => {
      if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) return onCmdControlClick(e);
      onClick(e);
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture [keyboard events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) such as `onKeyDown`, `onKeyPress`, `onKeyUp`.

```
 const keyboardEventHandler = (e) => {
    if (e === "Shift") {
      // do something
      console.log("Shift is pressed");
    } else {
      console.log(`${e} is pressed`);
    }
  };
return(
<input onKeyDown={(e) => keyboardEventHandler(e.key)} type="text"/>
)
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboard-events-njnyg)

Comment: Dmitriif, thank you for your help too